I gave my frozen fried rice a flavor I only get when I get fried rice from a Hibachi restaurant. How can I do this again without creating smoke?
The other day I used my stainless steel pan to cook my frozen fried rice. I have done this often.
This time I accidentally left the stove to preheat the pan on its highest setting. When I sprayed in my vegetable oil it IMMEDIATELY smoked. Undeterred for some reason I threw on my frozen fried rice an turned the stove way down. Even tossed it a lil way above the burner.
What I stumbled into was this flavor I have been trying to replicate at home for quite awhile but did not realize may be more about the time/temperature than anything else. I have cooked frozen fried rice in a stainless steel but it never had this flavor I associate with fried rice from a Hibachi Restaurunt.
It was a bit tougher than normal, almost glazed, and had this delicious umami flavor to it. Little corners of some of the bits of rice were burned a little but overall this cleaned up easily except for the polymerized oil on the pan which did NOT come out without a fight.
What did cooking at such a high temperature here do to add in this flavor and texture change? Is it a temperature where vegetable oil will smoke and I should just deal with it or is there a lower temperature I can get away with potentially?
I thought it might be the mallard reaction and maybe it is but I have cooked my frozen fried rice at lower temperatures before and still seen browning and fond form without that flavor being added.

Sounds like "Wok hei"

YES these are both so useful. Thankyou!

In that case, this will probably get closed as duplicate. There are tons of answers on here about wok hei.

Yeah totally good with that. Probably good to keep this up so that there are more search terms pointing people towards said other question(s)
